# How to remove/disable the output messages of gcloud CLI commands

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, stderr, gcloud, gcloud-cli

For example:

```
gcloud compute disks create --size=10GB my-data-disk
```

would print 2 things:

1. Warning:

   ```
   WARNING: You have selected a disk size of under [200GB]. This may result in poor I/O performance. For more information, see: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#pdperformance.
   ```

   This can be eliminated with `--verbosity error`
2. Status:

   ```
   Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/sigma-project-12345/zones/europe-west1-c/disks/my-data-disk].
   NAME          ZONE           SIZE_GB TYPE        STATUS
   my-data-disk europe-west1-c 10      pd-standard READY
   ```

   This I don't know how to disable, other then redirecting `stderr`, which of course I don't want because I still have to see if an error happened.

The `-q` argument does not remove it.

Answer (score 14):

The `--no-user-output-enabled` or `--user-output-enabled=false` flags seem to be what you are looking for.

Try this:

`gcloud compute disks create --size=10GB my-data-disk --no-user-output-enabled`

Answer (score 1):

@Vilas's answer is correct however please note that --no-user-output-enabled broke in some cases around version 141.0. See this issue - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36076836

Comment: thanks Sam, seems to have been fixed and closed in 2019, will give it a try and feedback on this page if I experience any issues for any one else who reads this

Answer (score 1):

To permanently disable the survey prompt, run:

```
gcloud config set survey/disable_prompts True
```

FROM : https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/survey

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to disable all the related warnings

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", "Your application has authenticated using end user credentials")
```

Comment: This seems interesting but how to use it?